# A crontab to move completed uploads from one dir to another?

Tags: linux, file, cron, move

I'm using the following crontab, once an hour, to move any files with the .mp3 extension from the dir "webupload" to the dir "complete" :

```
60 * * * * find usr/webupload -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp3" -exec mv {} usr/webupload/complete \;
```

The problem is that "webupload" contains lots of partial files being transferred.

I've read about a lot of different ways to achieve this but I think i'm more confused now than I was when I started!

What is the best practice or easiest way to only move the completed uploads?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be hard to tell when a file is completely written unless it is renamed when the download is completed, but you could change your `find` command and add `-mmin +1` so that it only looks for files which have been modified more than 1 minutes ago (meaning that download is likely completed).  Also, you should use `/` at the beginning of your paths rather than the relative paths your using:

```
60 * * * * find /usr/webupload -type f -mmin +1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp3" -exec mv {} /usr/webupload/complete \;
```

You could obviously make the modification time longer (eg. 10 minutes `-mmin +10`) if you want to be more certain that the file has been downloaded.